# Cascading sum hierarchy using recursive cte

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I'm trying to perform recursive cte with postgres but  I can't wrap my head around it. In terms of performance issue there are only 50 items in **TABLE 1** so this shouldn't be an issue.

**TABLE 1 (expense):**

```
id | parent_id | name
------------------------------
1 | null | A
2 | null | B
3 | 1 | C
4 | 1 | D
```

**TABLE 2 (expense_amount):**

```
ref_id | amount
-------------------------------
3 | 500
4 | 200
```

**Expected Result:**

```
id, name, amount
-------------------------------
1 | A | 700
2 | B | 0
3 | C | 500
4 | D | 200
```

**Query**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT
    expenses.id,
    name,
    parent_id,
    expense_amount.total
  FROM expenses
  WHERE expenses.parent_id IS NULL
  LEFT JOIN expense_amount ON expense_amount.expense_id = expenses.id
  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    expenses.id,
    expenses.name,
    expenses.parent_id,
    expense_amount.total
  FROM cte
  JOIN expenses ON expenses.parent_id = cte.id
  LEFT JOIN expense_amount ON expense_amount.expense_id = expenses.id
)
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(amount)
FROM cte
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Results

```
id | sum
--------------------
1 | null
2 | null
3 | 500
4 | 200
```

Comment: Do you only want the top level sum? Or intermediate "parents" as well? e.g. what would expect if you add a row with `id = 5, parent_id = 4, name = 'E'` to the `expense` table and a row with `5,100` to the expense_amount table? Should the row for `D` then show `300` or still `200`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a conditional sum() for only the root row:

```
with recursive tree as (
   select id, parent_id, name, id as root_id
   from expense
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, p.root_id
   from expense c 
     join tree p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select e.id, 
       e.name,
       e.root_id,
       case 
         when e.id = e.root_id then sum(ea.amount) over (partition by root_id)
         else amount
       end as amount
from tree e
  left join expense_amount ea on e.id = ea.ref_id
order by id;
```

I prefer doing the recursive part first, then join the related tables to the result of the recursive query, but you could do the join to the expense_amount also inside the CTE.

Online example: http://rextester.com/TGQUX53703

---

However, the above only aggregates on the top-level parent, not for any intermediate non-leaf rows.

If you want to see intermediate aggregates as well, this gets a bit more complicated (and is probably not very scalable for large results, but you said your tables aren't that big)

```
with recursive tree as (
   select id, parent_id, name, 1 as level, concat('/', id) as path, null::numeric as amount
   from expense
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, p.level + 1, concat(p.path, '/', c.id), ea.amount
   from expense c 
     join tree p on c.parent_id = p.id
     left join expense_amount ea on ea.ref_id = c.id
)
select e.id, 
       lpad(' ', (e.level - 1) * 2, ' ')||e.name as name,
       e.amount as element_amount,
       (select sum(amount) 
        from tree t
        where t.path like e.path||'%') as sub_tree_amount,
       e.path
from tree e
order by path;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/MCE96740

The query builds up a path of all IDs belonging to a (sub)tree and then uses a scalar sub-select to get all child rows belonging to a node. That sub-select is what will make this quite slow as soon as the result of the recursive query can't be kept in memory.

I used the `level` column to create a "visual" display of the tree structure - this helps me debugging the statement and understanding the result better. If you need the real name of an element in your program you would obviously only use `e.name` instead of pre-pending it with blanks.

Comment: Wow. How do you debug CTEs? I wasn't expecting this to be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get your query to work for some reason. Here's my attempt that works for the particular table you provided (parent-child, no grandchild) without recursion. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cef52/1/0)

```
    --- step 1: get parent-child data together 
    with parent_child as(
        select t.*, amount
        from
          (select e.id, f.name as name, 
              coalesce(f.name, e.name) as pname
            from expense e
            left join expense f
            on e.parent_id = f.id) t
        left join expense_amount ea 
        on ea.ref_id = t.id
    )

    --- final step is to group by id, name
    select id, pname, sum(amount)
        from
          (-- step 2: group by parent name and find corresponding amount
           -- returns A, B
            select e.id, t.pname, t.amount
              from expense e
              join (select pname, sum(amount) as amount
                    from parent_child
                    group by 1) t
              on t.pname = e.name
          -- step 3: to get C, D we union and get corresponding columns
          -- results in all rows and corresponding value
          union
          select id, name, amount
            from  expense e
          left join expense_amount ea
          on e.id = ea.ref_id
          ) t
    group by 1, 2 
    order by 1;
```